# Trying to use Scrapy to scrape data but only getting blank answers

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently trying to webscrape specific data from this website but when I crawl using the cmd after this the json and csv files just end up being blank what am I doing wrong?

```
import scrapy
class RatesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rates'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.ratehub.ca/best-mortgage-rates/5-year/fixed']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.ratehub.ca/best-mortgage-rates/5-year/fixed/']
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="AllRatesTable_SpQFd"]//tr'):
            yield {
                'Rate' : row.xpath('td[1]//span').get(),
                'Provider': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').get(),
            }
```

I've tried to fix this in a couple ways including changing the xpath for the table but it just endsup with there not even being labels in the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the time to fully test your code (i.e. your xpath expressions) but I can give you some top level pointers:

1. A) In `allowed_domains`,  you should only include `ratehub.ca` and not the entire link as you currently have it. For more info see [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html).
   *Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, then add 'example.com' to the list*
2. **A)** In your `start_urls`, notice that you are duplicating `http://` part, that for sure won't work.
   **B)** In your `start_urls`, you should remove the last `/`, as if i'm not mistaken scrapy adds that automatically.
3. **Are you sure the table does not disappear when you disable Java-Script**? I tried searching the HTML tree with your `xpath` for the table `//*@id="AllRatesTable_SpQFd"]//tr`  but nothing was returned back. I would suggest make sure you disable java-script and try again to make sure it works.
4. By adding `text()` in the last part of the below statements, you make sure you extract the text back. Is 'rate' not a text?

```
yield {
                'Rate' : row.xpath('td[1]//span//text()').get(),
                'Provider': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').get(),
            }
```

Comment: Hey first of all thank you for your comment. I fixed the first two points you brought up I'm a little confused on 3, The table does indeed disappear when I disable Javascript but what does that mean in this case when I try to copy full Xpath after reenabling that's still what I get. Finally for #4 I did have it as text() originally but when I tried to copy Xpath it didn't come up as text so I changed it but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately scrapy (by itself) cannot be used to crawl JS dependent websites. Typically for JS you use a headless browser that will execute your javascript. Splash with scrapy-splash middleware and Selenium are two popular choices there.. Since the table disappears once you disable it, it means it probably means it can't be rendered using scrapy, as the information is not there without JavaScript.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate then at this point I think I may just look for another data source or location to scrape this information from and try out Selenium  at a later date thank you for your help.

Comment: I would agree to that. I think using Selenium is a good choice, especially for beginners like us, as it is simple to use and has extensive documentation online. Thanks for accepting the answer.